# C# - Use of repository with dapper very slow

Tags: c#, repository, repository-pattern

I have a small test project to get information of suppliers like the parts and invoices.
For that I tried to use repository pattern. But I'm not sure if I use this correctly.

Everything is working, but it is very slow.
I have several classes like:

```
 public class SupplierPart
    {
        public int PartId { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; } 
        public string PartName { get; set; }
...
```

For every class I create an Interface like this:

```
 public interface ISupplierPartRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<SupplierPart> GetAllSupplierParts();
        IEnumerable<SupplierPart> GetAllSupplierPartsOfSupplier(int SupplierId);
        void UpdateSupplierPart(SupplierPart part);       
    }
```

And then the repository:

```
 public class SupplierPartRepository : ISupplierPartRepository
    {

 public IEnumerable<SupplierPart> GetAllSupplierParts()
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                string q = @"SELECT ...";
                
                return db.Query<SupplierPart>(q, commandType: CommandType.Text);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SupplierPart> GetAllSupplierPartsOfSupplier(int SupplierId)
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                string q = @"SELECT ...";

                return db.Query<SupplierPart>(q, new { SupplierId });
            }
        }

public void UpdateSupplierPart(SupplierPart part)
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(AppConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
...
}
}
```

And that's how I use it in my form:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = supplierPartRepository.GetAllSupplierParts().ToList();

Code_Actions.FillComboBox(combobox2, productGroupRepository.GetAllProductGroups(), "GroupName", "GroupId");
Code_Actions.FillComboBox(combobox3, partRepository.GetAllParts(), "Number", "Number");
Code_Actions.FillComboBox(combobox4, unitRepository.GetAllUnits(), "UnitText", "UnitId");

...
```

And if do it like this it is very slow. If I only use the code for filling the dataGridView1 it is very fast. So I think this is not the best way of doing that?!

What can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: So last three queries (GetAll*) are taking so long, maybe you have many data in those tables?

Comment: No very less data. Also the GetAllParts. For every query ~5-10 data records.

Comment: have you tested your queries in your database? how much time takes there?

Answer (score 0):

I hope issue is your creating too many database connections at a time check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188611/how-long-does-it-take-to-create-a-new-database-connection-to-sql).
Try to use unit of work with repository pattern that will solve this issue.
Good unit of work [codebase](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork)